# partition table looks different between Linux and Windows

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, gparted, fdisk

I'm having some odd issues after deleting and resizing an NTFS partition with Gparted. Windows doesn't seem to see the same partition table as Linux.

At first, the deleted partition showed up as 0-block partition of unknown type in `fdisk`. Since `fdisk` wouldn't let me delete it, I used `sfdisk` to do it manually.

The current status:

- `fdisk` shows 4 partitions
- `gparted` shows entire drive as unallocated
- Windows still sees the old partition table, can't find system files at their old location, thus fails to boot

What's puzzling me is that `gparted`'s opinion conflicts with `fdisk`'s.

Answer (score 0):

GParted (or most tools built around libparted) tends to show any disk with even the most minor partition table error as empty. This makes this whole family of tools next to useless for recovering from partition table errors. You can ignore them for your current problem.

You'll have to post more information for a better diagnosis; the fact that `fdisk` shows four partitions and Windows sees a different partition table is much too little data. Post back with the output from the relevant tools -- cut-and-pasted text from `fdisk` (add four spaces to the start of each line to keep it properly formatted) and a screen shot of the Windows partitioning tool, for instance.

Comment: I've finally resorted to starting from stratch and using backups. I did image the drive before, just in case. PS: I think your point should best be put in a comment, rather than an actual answer, as it's commonly done here.